# How to iter throw rows in pandas and compare with the rest of the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops, iteration

I have a dataframe like the folllowing with data of search results for flights

```
search_id  total_fare  changes_airport
abc        101         False
abc        121         True
abc        105         True
abd        120         True
```

Now I want to add a column called "alternatives" that for each row returns True if there is another row with:

- The same search_id
- A total_fare difference of less than 10
- changes_airport == False

I was trying something like:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[row,'alternatives']=bool(dfs[(df.changes_airport==False)&_
    (df.search_id==row['search_id'])&_
    (df.total_fare<row['total_fare']+10)].shape[0])
```

What I find difficult is to iter over rows and at the same time analyze the rest of the dataframe.

I would like to know the right syntax and maybe a more efficient way to perform it.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by total_fare difference of less than 10? Also can you post the expected output for the above sample df?

Comment: row three should return True because there is another row (row 1) with the same search_id, changes_airport==False and 105-101 is less than ten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution that assumes that the original data frame is named df:

```
import pandas as pd

# Group by id and find minimum value
df1 = df.groupby('search_id').min()

# Keep only id with changes_airport == False
df1 = df1[df1['changes_airport'] == False].reset_index()

# Merge the two data frames - creates additional columns in df2
df2 = pd.merge(df, df1, how='outer', on=['search_id'])

# Fill the new column based on the difference between current cell total_fare 
# and the minimum fare for the respective search_id
df2['alternatives'] = (df2['total_fare_x'] - df2['total_fare_y']) < 10

# Drop auxiliary columns
del df2['changes_airport_y'], df2['total_fare_y']

print(df2)

   changes_airport_x search_id  total_fare_x  alternatives
0              False       abc           101          True
1               True       abc           121         False
2               True       abc           105          True
3               True       abd           120         False
```

Comment: Ok great. I would only invert the first two steps.

Comment: Just for sport, is there a way to perform the same task with transform, np.where or iterrows...?

Comment: The tricky part of your problem is the value of cells in a column is determined based on a value in another cell in a different row and column. I am not sure this is traightforward to do using the commands you have listed. The other issue is speed. iterrows applies the function row by row and is bound to be slower. If I can't assign the cell value directly, I would personally stick with joins. They are very powerful.

Comment: Ok Thanks a lot!!